# Pre loading images with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have checked a few other forums and can't get it to work. On the website there are three images with a hover effect. On the first page load the hover effect takes a second to load the background image.

Here is what I have inbetween my

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function MM_preloadImages() { //v3.0
  var d=document; if(d.images){ if(!d.MM_p) d.MM_p=new Array();
    var i,j=d.MM_p.length,a=MM_preloadImages.arguments; for(i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i].indexOf("#")!=0){ d.MM_p[j]=new Image; d.MM_p[j++].src=a[i];}}
}
</script>
```

then I have this in my body tag:

```html
<body  <?php body_class(); ?> onLoad="MM_preloadImages('http://agconcretepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/designreplace2.png','http://agconcretepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ConcreteREPLACE.png','http://agconcretepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/no_title_paver.png')">
```

Doesn't work for the three images I need preloaded. I also copy and pasted this from google searching, and tried putting it in various places in my header.php to no avail.

```js
       <script type="text/javascript">

            if (document.images) {
                img1 = new Image();
                img2 = new Image();
                img3 = new Image();

                img1.src = "http://agconcretepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/designreplace2.png";
                img2.src = "http://agconcretepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/ConcreteREPLACE.png";
                img3.src = "http://agconcretepro.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/no_title_paver.png";
            }

    </script>
```

Any help here would be awesome! Thank you!

Comment: doesn't work **HOW**? your preloader doesn't fire? loads the wrong images?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<body imageURL1="path/to/your/image1" imageURL2="path/to/your/image2" imageURL3="path/to/your/image3" imageURL4="path/to/your/image4">
<div id="home-image-container"></div>
```

Then using jQuery you can do:

```
function home_load_background(){
//Load first image and start timer

var $body = $('body');

var $fader = $('#home-image-container');

var $temp = $('<div />');

var images = [];

images.push(
    $body.attr('imageurl1'),
    $body.attr('imageurl2'),
    $body.attr('imageurl3'),
    $body.attr('imageurl4')
);

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    var $img = $('<img />').attr('src', images[i]);

    $temp.append($img);
};

    $fader
        .append($temp.find('img'))
        .find('img').first().on('load', function(){
           $fader.fsslider({
                width: $fader.width(),
                height: $fader.height(),
                spw: 5,
                sph: 4,
                delay: 8000,
                sDelay: 100,
                effect: 'rand',
                texture: 'strip1',
                navigation: false,
                animDuration: 1200,

            });
        });
}
```

And on document ready you can call your function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    home_load_background();
});
```

Has you can see i used FSSlider to show the other images. However, you can use whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

I answered the question myself without any JS which works out well.

With HTML, right after the body tag:

```
<div id="preload">
    <img src="path/to/image>
    <img src="path/to/image>
    <img src="path/to/image>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
div#preload{display: none}
```

For anybody if they come across this problem! And